# Blender Render Texture Painting

Tags: texturing, blender-internal-render-engine, texture-painting

So, I have been looking through a lot of videos about Texture Painting. But mostly, they are in Cycles Render, I use Blender Render. However i did find tutorials about Texture Painting in Blender Render. But whenever they use it they say "Blender automatically adds a texture itself" and goes into Texture Paint mode with being able to draw. But when I literally do everything they said. Unwrap it, Add a new texture and go into Texture Paint mode. I did it all. But when i do go into Texture Paint, it says "Missing Data" and "Missing Texture Slot". And the cube i was supposed to Paint is also white.
I might be missing something really obvious. But i cant seem to understand what it is.
Some help would be appreciated.
Like really, I feel desperate once again.

(If you need more info I can spend hours typing it to you in the chat. I have no life, so i'm almost always online.)
(I use Blender v2.79)

Answer (score 2):

I think you're missing one main point: a UV map is needed to make a correspondence between the mesh faces and a texture to paint to. And this UV is to be set up in the texture panel.

So the recipe is the following:

- Have a mesh object
- Go in edit mode <kbd>Tab</kbd>
- Select vertices and unwrap (there is several ways to unwrap, I consider here the simple one): use <kbd>U</kbd> the "smart UV project" and validate

[image]

- Create an image
- Go to the texture panel
- Choose the texture type as "image or movie"
- Choose the image created above
- Set the mapping to UV

[image]

Now you can paint:

[image]

Note that there are possibly several slots to paint to and you can add other textures or texture types from the "slot" tab available in paint mode:

[image]

In complement, here is how to create the image:

- Open a new view
- Set it to "UV/Image editor"
- Use the "image" menu then "new image"
- Validate the panel that opens, eventually renaming the image as you want

[image]

Comment: I'm so sorry if i'm being a pain in the butt. But can you send the images in like some other ways? Maybe gyazo or stuff? Because i kind of didnt get the "Create an image" part. Not because you didnt explain it though. Just because i'm dumb.

Comment: ok, I had that here. You can see the gif here? No need to use gyazo?

Comment: Nope, cant see anything, I cant view imgur links for some reason.

Comment: Here is a wetransfer link to a zip containing the gif https://we.tl/Mex2NAAGzZ (I cannot redo all for gyazo...)

Comment: Dude thank you so much for spending your time on my problem. I got it fixed and my god do i feel happy. You're incredible man. Thanks! <3

Comment: Good if that helps you